# Computing the marginal expected shortfall (MES)

Tags: matlab, finance

I found the following Matlab code to compute the Marginal Expected Shortfall (MES). I understand the code but the mathematical part is not clear to me. More specifically, I don't understand these two lines:
`r0_n = 4 / (3 * length(rm_0));` and `h = r0_s * r0_n ^0.2;`. Why do we need to do these computations and what do they represent?

```
rm = r(:,1); % index returns 
rm_0 = rm - mean(rm);

rf = r(:,2);  % security returns
rf_0 = rf - mean(rf);

[p,h] = dcc_gjrgarch(r); % p is the conditional correlations 
                         % and h is the conditional variances 
sm = sqrt(h(:,1));
sf = sqrt(h(:,2));
rho = squeeze(p(1,2,:));

c = quantile(rm_0,a);
z = sqrt(1 - rho.^2);

u = rm_0 ./ sm;
x = ((rf_0 ./ sf) - (rho .* u)) ./ z;

r0_n = 4 / (3 * length(rm_0));
r0_s = min([std(rm_0 ./ sm) (iqr(rm_0 ./ sm) ./ 1.349)]);
h = r0_s * r0_n ^0.2;

f = normcdf(((c ./ sm) - u) ./ h);
f_sum = sum(f);

k1 = sum(u .* f) ./ f_sum;
k2 = sum(x .* f) ./ f_sum;

mes = -1 .* min((sf .* rho .* k1) + (sf .* z .* k2),0);""
```

Moreover, I believe this code replicates more or less the following formula used to compute the Expected Shortfall.
[SE Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mguyx.jpg)